# Is it possible to use Google Drive API to convert html to doc?

Tags: php, google-api

I'm trying to use Google Drive's PHP API to convert HTML to doc. I can successfully upload my html file to Google Drive. But due to the documentation of the API (very poor) I don't know how to convert that file to a valid .doc file and bring it back to my server. Did anyone did this before? Any tricks? Tutorials etc...

Comment: Is converting HTML to .doc even even a feature Drive offers?

Comment: Well yeah, Google Docs converts HTML to DOC for sure. But I don't know how to do it with the API